# Intercept SwiftUI NavigationBar Back Button Press

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to intercept the `UIControl` event (or any event, for that matter) when the `NavigationBar` back button is pressed within a swiftui closure? Or when the swipe gesture is used?

I'm trying to dig into UIViewControllerRepresentable to see how to tie in to delegate methods inside the `NavigationController` (i.e. `UINavigationControllerDelegate`) and convert those through logic within the UIKit component to generate a 'didNavigateToPrevious' signal, caused by either form of intended navigation through the stack (i.e. **not** switching tabs) such as tapping the back button or swipe gesturing.

I've also tried overriding `didMove(toParent:)` on a subclassed UIHostingController, which so far is not getting invoked at all.

Then neatly provide a `ViewModifier` that appends a closure to be called whenever the delegate method is invoked.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of

```
NotifyingNavigationView {
   Text("Hello")
}.didNavigateBackward {
    // access environmentObject
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Detail View")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            print("Initial value: \(self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented)")

        }
        .onDisappear() {
            if(self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented == false) {
                print("You click the back button")
            }

        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView())
                { Text("Go to view 2") }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to "be notified" by the UINavigationController behind the scenes in SwiftUI whenever the "back" bar button item is pressed.

Comment: That above does that, when you click back, it prints a message, you can substitute the print for whatever function you'd like @elight

Comment: To me, that would suggest that the message is printed when a new view is pushed onto the stack as well. Is that what happens? I'll test it unless you already have...

Comment: I already tested it. In this particular case since your example is very simple, when ever you transition from the second view (I called it View 2) to any view whatsoever, I'll print that. It's not really tied to the "Back" button. @elight

Comment: Oh I see. Well, not to sound prickly but that's why I was specific in the question, even going so far as outlining what an API could look like. I'll post back with what I find.

Comment: @elight I modified my answer, run it and see if that's what you wanted, I believe it is

Comment: I see the message printed when clicking on the navigation link to push the next view onto the stack. This doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't work but not in my case. I may have to expand my question. Thank you!

Comment: @elight yep, if that doesn't work for you then the question needs to be expanded with more code, because as far as what you asked, that is a correct solution

Comment: @elight if it is a whole new question with more functionality consider creating a new post

Comment: Then again, I do think the question is pretty straight forward.